# How to show secondary y axis and line series in powerpoint in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint

I got struck with exporting charts and grid to ppt using asp.net.Here in the below code I was able to show chart but not grid. My chart consists of two bar series and two line series which I'm unable to show and the line series should bind with secondary y-axis (right side). Here I'm providing my code so any modifications or any sample code is much appreciated. This was developed with Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

In the aspx.cs page below code

```
   try
        {
            bool bAssistantOn;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application objApp;
            Presentations objPresSet;
            _Presentation objPres;
            Slides objSlides;
            _Slide objSlide;
            TextRange objTextRng;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes objShapes;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape objShape;
            SlideShowWindows objSSWs;
            SlideShowTransition objSST;
            SlideShowSettings objSSS;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideRange objSldRng;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart objChart;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.DataSheet dataSheet;

            //Create a new presentation based on a template.
            objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            objApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
            objPres = objPresSet.Open(@"D:\Template.pptx", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            //.potx file is the template file of powerpoint.
            //Take a template file remove all it's slides and save it.
            //Then give it's physical path instead of it.
            objSlides = objPres.Slides;

            //Build Slide #1
            //Add text to the slide title, format the text. Also add a chart to the
            //slide and change the chart type to a 3D pie chart.
            objSlide = objSlides.Add(1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
            objTextRng = objSlide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
            objTextRng.Text = "My Chart";
            objTextRng.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS";
            objTextRng.Font.Size = 48;

            objChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart)objSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(150, 150, 480, 320, "MSGraph.Chart.8", "", MsoTriState.msoFalse, "", 0, "", MsoTriState.msoFalse).OLEFormat.Object;
            dataSheet = objChart.Application.DataSheet;

            // objChart.Legend.LegendEntries();
            //objChart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlAxisType.xlValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);

            for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                        dataSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["ProductGroup"];// x-axis values
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    //objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlBarOfPie;

                    dataSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "ActualsQTD"; // Legend 1
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dataSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j - 1]["ActualsQTD"])/1000;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    //objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlBarOfPie;

                    dataSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "ForecastQTD"; // Legend 2
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dataSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j - 1]["ForecastQTD"])/1000;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    //objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlLine;

                    dataSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "QTDRatio"; // Legend 3
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dataSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j-1]["QTDRatio"];
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    //objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlLine;

                    dataSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "Target Attain"; // Legend 4
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dataSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j-1]["Target Attain"];
                    }
                }

                objChart.Application.Update();
            }
            //objChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlChartType.xlLine; //changing the graph type : by default pie chart
            objChart.SeriesCollection(2);
            objChart.Legend.Position = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionBottom;
            objChart.HasTitle = true;
            objChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart";

            ///Build Slide #2:
            ///Change the background color of this slide only. Add a text effect to the slide
            ///and apply various color schemes and shadows to the text effect.
            objSlide = objSlides.Add(2, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
            objSlide.FollowMasterBackground = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            objShapes = objSlide.Shapes;
            objShape = objShapes.AddTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect27, "The End", "Impact", 96, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 230, 200);

            //Modify the slide show transition settings for all slides in
            //the presentation.
            int[] SlideIdx = new int[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) SlideIdx[i] = i + 1;
            objSldRng = objSlides.Range(SlideIdx);
            objSST = objSldRng.SlideShowTransition;
            objSST.AdvanceOnTime = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            objSST.AdvanceTime = 3;
            objSST.EntryEffect = PpEntryEffect.ppEffectBoxOut;

            //Prevent Office Assistant from displaying alert messages:
            ////bAssistantOn = objApp.Assistant.On;
            ////objApp.Assistant.On = false;

            //Run the Slide show
            //objSSS = objPres.SlideShowSettings;
            //objSSS.StartingSlide = 1;
            //objSSS.EndingSlide = 2;![enter image description here][1]
            //objSSS.Run();

            //Wait for the slide show to end.
            ////objSSWs = objApp.SlideShowWindows;
            ////while (objSSWs.Count >= 1) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            //Reenable Office Assisant, if it was on:
            ////if (bAssistantOn)
            ////{
            ////    objApp.Assistant.On = true;
            ////    objApp.Assistant.Visible = false;
            ////}

            //Close the presentation without saving changes and quit PowerPoint.
            objPres.SaveAs(@"D:\Sample", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            //"D:\Sample" is the location where the ppt will be saved.
            objPres.Close();
            objApp.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");

            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");

            sb.Append("alert('");

            sb.Append(ex.Message);

            sb.Append("')};");

            sb.Append("</script>");

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());

       }
```

[image: My chart]

by above code I'm able to show only barcharts but not both bar and line series with secondary y-axis.

Thanks in advance.